# House / home external skin for heat shield materials

Tags: materials, heat-transfer, architecture

Concrete/brick homes in tropical areas are hot due to direct sunlight. Please suggest external siding materials or design to give heat shielding. Please give reasons (and if possible pros & cons).
Some ideas are using wood siding, because wood thermal capacity is low so that any heat will blown away by wind (but interstitial space behind the wood may infested with animals). Or using living plant leaves, since they give shade and heat on leaves blown away by wind (but may have problems with mould growth, or plant maintenance).

Comment: This is ... much too broad.  Spend some time and focus on the specific problem you have, and then [edit] the question to address that specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an over-hanging roof which will then shade the walls. Over-hanging roofs are seen in many countries, but not only for sun but also for snow (eg Switzerland) to stop or reduce the chance of snow piling up against the wooden chalet walls

This type of design is called "passive solar design" and there are many links / books that can be found.

Comment: Good! Please add other ideas, I'm aure you are resourceful.

Comment: Passive solar design is a large topic, so it would be better for you to be resourceful and start to investigate it yourself.